# window.alert close handler?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there an easy way to execute some code AFTER the closing of a window.alert popup? I have a substantially large library to load and my plan was to throw up a welcome message like

```
window.alert("Welcome to my site!")
```

just to give the browser a second or two to make sure everything loads. I'm using window.confirm right now, as I can catch the confirm event after the button has been clicked, but there's really no need for me to have two options. Any suggestions on how to catch the "confirm" on the "Ok" message for window.alert()? Also, will your solution work cross browser (or at least on the later editions of FF, IE, and Safari)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.alert()` stops the execution flow of the script, so your it's enough to put your code after the call to `alert()`.

Example:

```
alert("I am waiting for you to click OK");
/* Your code here */
```

However, if you want to check if "everything" has been loaded, this method will likely not work. Consider using, for example, the body's onload event handler.

```
<body onload="mycode();">
  ....
</body>
```

For advanced methods, consider using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library, which lets you achieve your purpose by means of the `$(document).ready()` handler.

Comment: document.ready is not just an "elegant way" (whatever that means) it distinguishes itself from window.onload by waiting only for the dom to finish loading and not for all the images on the page as well.

Comment: OK. I've edited the answer. I used the adjective "elegant" in all senses: power, portability (aka cross-browser) and ease.

Answer (score 0):

`alert` is not an asynchronous method. No javascript runs until `alert` closes.

You should really be using jQuery's `$(documnet).ready()` or an equivalent from another library to wait for the page to load before javascript execution.

Answer (score 0):

The code line next to

```
window.alert("Welcome to my site!")
```

will execute immediately after the alert window closes.